# gwt server send notice to all opened apps

Tags: gwt

In my app I need functionality like this: the privileged user who have logged in using the gwt app I work on pushes a button, request goes to server and server sends a notice to all other logged in users, then their apps show some kind of alert. The one step I cannot figure out is sending notice to all logged in users - how to establish some kind of clien-server connection that hangs till the privileged user triggers a notice and how would server gather info about all logged in users? Can you give any suggestions how to deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach if you are using GWT-RPC is a "long call".

Your clients make a call GWT-RPX call and the server side sits there doing nothing. Eventually your privileged user hits the button, and the server side signals all the "waiting" clients - their long RPC call returns and they do something.

You may find you need to wrap this in a class: the long call may time out depending on server config, so you really want a loop that waits on the server side for x seconds, and then returns with a code that tells the client that the trigger didn't happen, so the call should be made again.

This functionality is probably already provided by some 3rd party lib, but I hand rolled it a while back and it works ;-)

From memory on the server side I had all the client calls waiting on a semaphore, and when the privileged user server side call just had to make sure it released the right number (so that all the waiting clients got signaled to continue)
You could do something simpler with just a synchronised variable and a loop.

Client - consider this pseudo code, it's not really thought out that well.

```
// lock needs to be a common var so all threads are working on the same one.
// probably a static?
int counter = 0;
while(counter < 5) {
    synchronized(lock) {
        if (lock) {
            // return "success"
        }
        counter++;
        sleep(1000); // sleep one second
    }
}
// return "try again"
```

The server size obviously needs a synchronized call to set `lock` to true so all the clients get to the `return success` chunk. You also need to reset lock to false somewhere.

Comment: how did u signal all the "waiting" clients? I thought I could use file,named fifo, now I am investigating unix domain sockets. Simultaneously I consider comet form rocket-gwt. I am little lost here.

Comment: I've added some description, does that clear things up at all?

Comment: yes, that makes things clear. My difficulty was that I thought the server side class is created for every request. On the contrary, the class is shared between request. I wonder why any tutorial I came across never mentioned that.

Comment: I'm not sure if its the same class or not - that is why you need to make sure your lock is shared between all instances.

Comment: It is up to the server to decide how many Servlet instances are needed. A instance may be shared between requests, but does not necessarily has to be. So having a common lock is crucial for this kind of solution. However, if you are having multiple servers (cluster or multi-line setup) this approach will fail however.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Errai-Bus](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ERRAI/Bus+Services?_sscc=t) for that purpose.
For example I have implemented a push notification. Whenever a user gives permission to an object to another user, the user will be notified.

There are two workflows:

1.) Subscribe to a Broadcast message:

Whenever a user logs in, your GWT app subscribes to a specific message subject (i.e. Broadcast) on the `MessageBus`  (Errai).
When a specific user pushes the button you send a Message over the `MessageBus` to the server. The server receives it and creates a broadcast message and sends it wiht the corresponding subject to which all logged in clients subscribed (i.e. Broadcast).

2.) Subscribe individual users:

Alternatively whenever a user logs in you, your GWT app creates a `Message` which contains some kind of unique id of the user and sends this `Message` to the server via the `MessageBus`. On the server you receive the `Message` and store the unique user id in a data structure (i.e. `Map`). 
In addition to this on the client side, your GWT app subscribes to messages with the subject equals to his owner user id (which you sent to the server before).
This way you can send to individual users.

You can also combine both workflows and have the GWT app subscribe to both, Broadcast messages as well as user messages.

Comment: correct if I am wrong isn't jboss competition to tomcat? Can I do what u describe do with tomcat in mind?

Comment: You don't have to use JBoss` application server. You can use `Errai-Bus` on any application server. I am actually deploying my app on `Jetty` and it works just fine. All you need is the GWT and server-side library and define the ErraiBus Servlet

Answer (score 0):

How about using a [Timer](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDelayed.html#running) on the client side to poll the server for changes. Just store your notice in the database, and let the clients check for new notices every couple of seconds. You don't need to lock on something on the server, so things will work with multiple servers as well. No need to keep track of who is logged. The active clients poll for new notices, if a client goes away it just stops polling.

Comment: that would be easy but 'd generate lots of traffic. I think app that sends request which "hangs" and is repeated only when necessary is better idea.

Comment: As always it depends. If you are writing an internal application for 100 user which polls every two minutes, this is an acceptable solution. You may not win an award, but you gain simplicity and portability.

Answer (score 0):

For a server to contact clients, your will have to implement something like [WebSockets](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/).

[Here's one sockets library that supports GWT](http://www.lightstreamer.com/).
Or you can see where [this search](https://www.google.com/search?q=gwt%20websockets) takes you.